# Usage of createElement/appendChild in IE8 for 512sha encrypted password?

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer-8, sha512

I want to encrypt a password from a login-form. So i have a submit-button in the index.php, which encodes the pw by onclick:

`<button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);">`

The js looks now like this:

```
function formhash(form, password) {
   var p = document.createElement("input");
   form.appendChild(p);
   p.name = "p";
   p.type = "hidden"
   p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
   password.value = "";
   form.submit();
}
```

The src works fine for FF & Chrome, but in IE8 it doesnt (there is no return-value). I think, the problem occurs from createElement or appendChild, but cant isolate it. Could someone help?

Many thanks

Comment: Any reason you preferred Client side encryption over Server side encryption. As it will definitely can be changed by user by changing hidden field before submit.

Comment: See php hashing functions like http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: Server side encryption ensure that Users do not have idea about encryption method used. If you want more security then you can easily more secure your password by adding salt and key-pairs methods

Comment: i use exactly this (salt and key-pairs), but client-sided.

Comment: Yes but salt key pairs definition still reside at client side and available to user if he analyze source html/javascript.